# Redirect loop in Laravel route caused by validation?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to use a single, matched controller to show and validate a form. I'm unsure if it is actually possible for this to work, as I haven't been successful.

For some reason, it won't even display the initial view - it just enters a 302 redirect loop and then times out.

Can anybody suggest why it might be doing this, and how I can resolve it? I didn't want to have to create more routes and method, hence the `match` as opposed to a separate `get` and `post`, with two separate controller methods.

**My Route**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/tracking', [
    'as' => 'tracking',
    'uses' => 'Tracking@index'
]);
```

**My Controller**

```
use App\Http\Requests\TrackingRequest;

class Tracking extends Controller {
    public function index(TrackingRequest $request) {
        return view('tracking.index');
    }
}
```

**My Validation**

```
class TrackingRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'reference.required' => 'Please enter a reference number.',
            'reference.numeric' => 'Please enter a valid reference number.',
            'reference.digits' => 'Please enter a valid reference number.',
            'reference.exists' => 'We don\'t have that reference number on our records.',
        ];
    }    
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'reference' => 'required|numeric|digits:10'
        ];
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
<h3>Welcome, {{ $job->name }} ({{ $job->reference }})</h3>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    @foreach ($updates as $update)
    <tr><td>
        <h3>{{ $update->title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ $update->content }}</p>
        <p><small><em>{{ $update->created_at }}</em></small></p>
    </td></tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. You should use RESTful controller, which has `create` method to generate the form and `store` method to persist the data. Also, it includes `edit`, `update` and `delete` methods which you can use for editing purposes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

For the forms you should use Laravel Collective:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

Then you will have just one simple route - `Route::resource` and you'll save yourself a lot of time and nerves. Also, you will not catch untrackable errors in that case.